# Free fall differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me if my solution is correct.

The diff equation is:

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = g-k/m\cdot v^2$$

$$v(0)=0$$

Comment: There is a typo in the last part of passing from $\ln(a^2 -v^2) = bt+C$ to $a^2-v^2 = e^{bt} + D$; it should be $a^2 - v^2 = D \cdot e^{bt}$. I think the rest is OK: just differentiate and see if it satisfies the diff.eq.

Comment: @Klaramun thank you for pointing that out I will check it :)

Comment: @Klaramun I have posted a third picture. I tried to see if it satisfies the diff but It doesn't. the IVP is $v(0) = 0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that $\int \frac 1{a-v}\,dv=-\ln (a-v)$ .

Comment: @TonyPiccolo omg thank you, I can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: The solution is $\,v=\sqrt {\frac {mg}k} \cdot \tanh \left(t \sqrt {\frac {gk}m} \right) $. See the _exponential_ definition of the hyperbolic tangent in your calculus textbook.